# Merge two columns then copy different data to new worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I want to merge two columns and then copy different data to a new worksheet.

[image: this is a fig for my data]

Someone helped me this VBA code to merge the data.

How do I insert a new worksheet and transfer data (according to the score) to it?

```vb
Sub MergeCols()
    Dim m As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    m = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A" & m + 1).Resize(m - 1, 2).Value = Range("B2").Resize(m - 1, 2).Value
    Range("B1").Resize(m).Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You could record a macro while performing the required steps, and then use that as a starting point.

Comment: thanks for your guaidance and suggestions. I will try that.

Comment: Hi Tim, I record a macro as you suggested. Could you please check and see how to improve it? but it is too long by 1836 characters to add the macro here.
Sub mcaro()
    Range("B2:B13").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("A14").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Columns("B:B").Select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Transform Data and Export to Multiple Sheets Based on Criteria

**Description**

- This code exports transformed data from one worksheet to multiple new worksheets in the same workbook, based on a given divisor. The data in the source worksheet is assumed to have a header row, and the unique values in the last column are used to determine which rows of data should be grouped together and exported to a new worksheet with a name based on the result of dividing that unique value by the divisor. Each new worksheet will contain two columns: "Name" and "Score", where "Name" corresponds to the columns before the last column in the source worksheet and "Score" corresponds to the last column.

[image]

**The Code**

```vb
Sub ExportTransformedData()

    ' Define constants.
    
    Const SRC_SHEET As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SRC_UNIQUE_COLUMN As Long = 3
    
    Const DST_SHEET As String = "Sheet2"
    Dim dHeaders(): dHeaders = VBA.Array("Name", "Score")
    
    Const DIVISOR As Long = 10
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Write the source data to the source array.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count - 1 ' no headers
    
    Dim sData(): sData = srg.Resize(srCount).Offset(1).Value
       
    ' Write the unique values and row numbers to a dictionary.
       
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
       
    Dim sr As Long, sStr As String
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        sStr = CStr(Int(sData(sr, SRC_UNIQUE_COLUMN) / DIVISOR))
        If Not dict.Exists(sStr) Then Set dict(sStr) = New Collection
        dict(sStr).Add sr
    Next sr
    
    ' Use the information from source array and the dictionary to return
    ' the result in the destination array to be copied to each worksheet.
    
    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = SRC_UNIQUE_COLUMN - 1
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dsh As Object, dData(), Key, rItem, dr As Long, dc As Long
    
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        ReDim dData(1 To 1 + dict(Key).Count * dcCount, 1 To dcCount)
        ' Write headers.
        For dc = 1 To dcCount
            dData(1, dc) = dHeaders(dc - 1)
        Next dc
        ' Write data.
        dr = 1
        For Each rItem In dict(Key)
            For dc = 1 To dcCount
                dr = dr + 1
                dData(dr, 1) = sData(rItem, dc)
                dData(dr, 2) = sData(rItem, SRC_UNIQUE_COLUMN)
            Next dc
        Next rItem
        ' Delete existing sheet.
        On Error Resume Next
            Set dsh = wb.Sheets(Key)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not dsh Is Nothing Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' delete without confirmation
                dsh.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            Set dsh = Nothing ' reset for the next iteration
        End If
        ' Add new sheet.
        With wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
            .Name = Key ' rename
            With .Range("A1").Resize(, dcCount)
                .Resize(dr).Value = dData ' write
                ' Format.
                .Font.Bold = True
                .EntireColumn.AutoFit
            End With
        End With
    Next Key
    
    ' Inform.
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Transformed data exported.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

**The Flow**

- The code begins by defining constants for the source worksheet name, the column index of the unique values to group on, the destination worksheet name, and the headers to use for the two columns in the new worksheets.
- Next, the code sets variables for the workbook, source worksheet, and source data range. The source data range is defined as the current region of cell A1 in the source worksheet, which includes all cells contiguous with and including cell A1. The number of rows in the source data range (excluding the header row) is also calculated.
- The source data is then stored in a two-dimensional array, and a dictionary object is created to store the unique values from the last column and the row numbers associated with each value.
- The code then iterates through the source data array and adds each row number to the appropriate collection in the dictionary based on the value in the last column divided by the divisor.
- After the dictionary has been populated, the code sets variables for the number of columns in the source data and turns off screen updating to speed up the code.
- The code then iterates through each unique key in the dictionary and creates a new two-dimensional array for the data to be exported to the new worksheet. The array is sized to accommodate the number of rows associated with the key multiplied by the number of columns in the source data, plus one row for the header row.
- The headers are then written to the first row of the array, and the data associated with each row number in the collection for the key is written to the array. The data for each row is copied from the source data array to the appropriate location in the new array, and the new array is written to a new worksheet with a name corresponding to the key value. If a worksheet with that name already exists, it is deleted without confirmation before creating the new worksheet.
- Finally, the screen updating is turned back on, and a message box is displayed indicating that the transformed data has been exported.

Comment: thank you so much for your kind help, your code is excellent and produced the expected results. I can use it to deal with my data, and also, I will try to understand the codes.